# Why doesn't Mathematica plot the data with uncertainties?

Tags: plotting, around

I'm trying to plot experimental data, but including uncertainties in the plot doesn't work. The data gets plotted properly when not including the uncertainties. Heres's the data without uncertainties:

```
GammaQList={{7.50133*10^13, 48.4534}, {9.39106*10^13, 56.8291}, {1.14533*10^14, 
  69.517}, {1.36724*10^14, 95.817}, {1.60315*10^14, 
  99.9031}, {1.85126*10^14, 120.554}, {2.10969*10^14, 
  139.376}, {2.37645*10^14, 154.812}, {2.64954*10^14, 
  164.555}, {2.92686*10^14, 170.44}, {3.20631*10^14, 
  143.062}, {3.48576*10^14, 170.547}, {3.76308*10^14, 
  199.743}, {4.03616*10^14, 235.026}, {4.30293*10^14, 
  250.496}, {4.56135*10^14, 241.207}, {4.80946*10^14, 217.222}}
```

The ploted data looks like this:

[image: data plot without uncertainties]

The data set with uncertainties looks like this:

```
GammaQuncertain={{7.50133*10^13, Around[
NumberForm[48.453373581114015`, 5], 
NumberForm[0.5289025737323284, 3]]}, {9.39106*10^13, Around[
NumberForm[56.82914855566321, 5], 
NumberForm[0.7183150056033312, 3]]}, {1.14533*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[69.51701099138343, 5], 
NumberForm[0.6735675857649294, 3]]}, {1.36724*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[95.81697312111692, 5], 
NumberForm[1.029982731623634, 3]]}, {1.60315*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[99.9030938806309, 5], 
NumberForm[0.7124579231717545, 3]]}, {1.85126*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[120.55350750441912`, 5], 
NumberForm[0.8876663773783958, 3]]}, {2.10969*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[139.37641443485998`, 5], 
NumberForm[0.8293506584246185, 3]]}, {2.37645*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[154.81194214292248`, 5], 
NumberForm[2.5559078253678917`, 3]]}, {2.64954*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[164.55492952408073`, 5], 
NumberForm[0.8676206236329481, 3]]}, {2.92686*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[170.4402010619802, 5], 
NumberForm[1.7916693551231961`, 3]]}, {3.20631*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[143.06244552905665`, 5], 
NumberForm[3.253307213244436, 3]]}, {3.48576*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[170.54749448566542`, 5], 
NumberForm[1.8035149181450574`, 3]]}, {3.76308*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[199.7430745877854, 5], 
NumberForm[2.1477932409963816`, 3]]}, {4.03616*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[235.02634436321688`, 5], 
NumberForm[1.2053708347248315`, 3]]}, {4.30293*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[250.49638278315143`, 5], 
NumberForm[1.3969608763890697`, 3]]}, {4.56135*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[241.20721666761688`, 5], 
NumberForm[1.3271575081627955`, 3]]}, {4.80946*10^14, Around[
NumberForm[217.22249209347999`, 5], 
NumberForm[2.8908609281753006`, 3]]}}
```

and the looks like this after using `ListPlot[GammaQuncertain]`:
[image: attempted plot with uncertainties]

I don't know what's wrong here, but i suspect it has something to do with the `NumberForm[...]` format of the table elements of `GammaQuncertain`. I don't know how un-NumberForm the table elements, it only appears when copy pasting it somewhere else than mathematica. I also don't know why the table elements are in `NumberForm` in the first place. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Get rid of the `NumberForm[]`s and it should work.

Comment: Try: `ListPlot[GammaQuncertain /. NumberForm[a_, _] :> a]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manually got rid of the `NumberForm[]` and the plot works.

```
GammaQuncertain = {{7.50133*10^13, 
   Around[48.453373581114015`, 0.5289025737323284]}, {9.39106*10^13, 
   Around[56.82914855566321, 0.7183150056033312]}, {1.14533*10^14, 
   Around[69.51701099138343, 0.6735675857649294]}, {1.36724*10^14, 
   Around[95.81697312111692, 1.029982731623634]}, {1.60315*10^14, 
   Around[99.9030938806309, 0.7124579231717545]}, {1.85126*10^14, 
   Around[120.55350750441912`, 0.8876663773783958]}, {2.10969*10^14, 
   Around[139.37641443485998`, 0.8293506584246185]}, {2.37645*10^14, 
   Around[154.81194214292248`, 2.5559078253678917`]}, {2.64954*10^14, 
   Around[164.55492952408073`, 0.8676206236329481]}, {2.92686*10^14, 
   Around[170.4402010619802, 1.7916693551231961`]}, {3.20631*10^14, 
   Around[143.06244552905665`, 3.253307213244436]}, {3.48576*10^14, 
   Around[170.54749448566542`, 1.8035149181450574`]}, {3.76308*10^14, 
   Around[199.7430745877854, 2.1477932409963816`]}, {4.03616*10^14, 
   Around[235.02634436321688`, 1.2053708347248315`]}, {4.30293*10^14, 
   Around[250.49638278315143`, 1.3969608763890697`]}, {4.56135*10^14, 
   Around[241.20721666761688`, 1.3271575081627955`]}, {4.80946*10^14, 
   Around[217.22249209347999`, 2.8908609281753006`]}}
```

[image]

Here is one (admittedly brutish)  way to remove the `NumberForm` programmatically.

```
GammaQuncertainClean = {#[[1]], 
    Around[#[[2, 1, 1]], #[[2, 2, 1]]]} & /@ GammaQuncertain
InputForm[GammaQuncertainClean]  

(*{{7.50133*^13, Around[48.453373581114015, 0.5289025737323284]}, 
 {9.39106*^13, Around[56.82914855566321, 0.7183150056033312]}, 
 {1.14533*^14, Around[69.51701099138343, 0.6735675857649294]}, 
 {1.36724*^14, Around[95.81697312111692, 1.029982731623634]}, 
 {1.60315*^14, Around[99.9030938806309, 0.7124579231717545]}, 
 {1.85126*^14, Around[120.55350750441912, 0.8876663773783958]}, 
 {2.10969*^14, Around[139.37641443485998, 0.8293506584246185]}, 
 {2.3764500000000003*^14, Around[154.81194214292248, 2.5559078253678917]}, 
 {2.64954*^14, Around[164.55492952408073, 0.8676206236329481]}, 
 {2.92686*^14, Around[170.4402010619802, 1.7916693551231961]}, 
 {3.20631*^14, Around[143.06244552905665, 3.253307213244436]}, 
 {3.48576*^14, Around[170.54749448566542, 1.8035149181450574]}, 
 {3.76308*^14, Around[199.7430745877854, 2.1477932409963816]}, 
 {4.03616*^14, Around[235.02634436321688, 1.2053708347248315]}, 
 {4.30293*^14, Around[250.49638278315143, 1.3969608763890697]}, 
 {4.56135*^14, Around[241.20721666761688, 1.3271575081627955]}, 
 {4.8094599999999994*^14, Around[217.22249209347999, 2.8908609281753006]}}*)
```